# switching nvidia profiles

Tags: xorg, nvidia

I have an old laptop with a nivdia card (360m) and I use powermizer to force it to run a very low clock. Heres my configuration at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf`

```
   Section "Device"
      Identifier "Device0"                                                  
      Driver    "nvidia"                                                                
      Option     "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerLevelAC=0x3"                                                                                                                                  
      Option     "NoLogo" "1"
   EndSection
```

Right now, whenever I watch movies or play a few games on Steam, I manually change the file so that gpu runs at a higher clock. Its a bit clumsy but it gets the job done.
Are there better ways to do this? ( Like a different X profile for different users)

Comment: Are there any steps you need to take after the file is edited to make X pick up the config?

Comment: of course, I need to restart X :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bash function to make the calling easier, and so you can add whatever you need to restart X easily.

The main bit is the Perl in place file edit (`perl -i`) and the regex for finding `PowerMizerLevelAC=".*"` and replacing it with the same text (`$1`) and your new value (`$value`).

Be aware that the regex will need to be more exact if you have multiple places the `PowerMizerLevelAC=""` can occur as this would replace all of them.

Run it with `set_nvidia_clock 0x1`

```bsh
function set_nvidia_clock() {
  local file="/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf"
  local level="$1"
  [ -z "$level" ] && echo "Error: specify new level as argument: set_nvidia_clock foo" && return 1

  perl -pi -e '
   BEGIN{ $value=shift;}
   s/"(PowerMizerLevelAC)=.*"/"${1}=${value}"/;
  ' "$level" "$file"

  if ! grep "PowerMizerLevelAC" "$file"; then 
    echo "Error: problem with replace"
    return 1
  fi

  # restart X 
  ##
}
```